# How can I convert lng and lat from OpenLayers to mapbox?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mapbox-gl-js

OpenLayers uses an array like this: `[15711464.77174924, 1340284.424706252]` to handle center's coordinates, but for `mapbox-gl` I should set a value between -90 to 90 and I get this error:

`Error: Invalid LngLat latitude value: must be between -90 and 90`

So, is there any way to convert a coordinates like: `15711464.77174924` to between -90 to 90?

Comment: `ol.proj.toLonLat` (as in line 45 of the exxample code in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html)

Comment: @Mike You know, we saved all coordinates using this format: `[15711464.77174924, 1340284.424706252]` in Database, but I need to convert between -90 to 90 then show them in new map which we created with `mapbox-gl` therefore, I should convert current format on runtime for the new map! something like a function or algorithm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spherical mercator coordinates assume the world is a sphere of radius 6378137 meters.  To convert to degrees (based on the OpenLayers source code https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/proj/epsg3857.js#L132-L134) the function would be

```
function toLonLat(input) {
    const RADIUS = 6378137;
    const HALF_SIZE = Math.PI * RADIUS;

    const lon = (180 * input[0]) / HALF_SIZE;
    const lat =
      (360 * Math.atan(Math.exp(input[1] / RADIUS))) / Math.PI - 90;

    return [lon, lat];
}
```